# PHP multidimensional array value replace with another value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pedigree Dry
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Professional Range
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pedigree Wet
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => PMM
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chappi
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Care & Treat
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sheba
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Whiskas Dry
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Whiskas Wet
            [1] => N/A
            [2] => N/A
            [3] => N/A
        )

)
```

The above code is an multidimensional array.But all array elements(except index) is N/A.I want to replace  all the N/A with 0. 
How can I replace all N/A with 0 ?

Comment: For something like this since almost all the values are `N/A` I would probably not bother changing them in the array and instead change them on output.

Comment: Like `echo $val == 'N/A' ? 0 : $val;` assuming a loop.

Comment: @Michael I know the above idea. i want to pass the above value to another function. In that case what i will do??

Comment: If you really need to modify it, then Ali's answer below is a good one.

Comment: I know that, no need to suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();    
foreach($array as $inner_array) {
    $newArray[] = str_replace("N/A", 0, $inner_array);
}
```

This loops over all the inner arrays and replaces all "N/A" with a zero and adds them to a new resultant array.

Working [**Demo**](http://3v4l.org/a1l0a)

Comment: how to str_replace a string in an array? str_replace replaces a string in string. basic syntax. anyway, i do not downvoted.

Comment: @lolka_bolka str_replace can replace all array values as it loops all over them. Read the documentation. The third parameter is `mixed` which means it can be an array. I also included a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function replaceNa($var) {
    if ($var == 'N/A' ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $var;
    }
}

$array = array(
    array('Pedigre dry', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'),
    array('Professional Range', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'),
    array('Pedigree Wet', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'),
    array('PMM', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'),
);


foreach ($array as $key => $item) {

    $array[$key] = array_map('replaceNa', $item);
}

var_dump ($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there's a better answer than this.. but you could always just do the nested foreach approach.

```
//loop through each Array (first level)
foreach ($arrays as $array) 
{
     //create two variables for each sub array so you have access to keys and values
     foreach ($array as $key=>$value) 
     {
         if ($value = "N/A")
         {
              $value = 0;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You may want to pass `$array` and `$value` by reference. `foreach ($array as $key=>&$value)`

Comment: You would need array references in the `foreach` to actually modify the loop while iterating it ([near the top of `foreach` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php))

Comment: This will not change the value of the element. Either `$array[$key] = 0;` or `foreach($array as &$value)` and then `$value = 0;`